# ¿Cómo puedo poner una dirección de un directorio si tiene espacios?

Tags: c, archivo, cmd, directorioactivo, cmder

Por ejemplo yo quiero usar el comando Move para mover un archivo de el escritorio a C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
pero si escribo "Move (El nombre del archivo) C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
pero me pone que la direccion "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start" no se pudo encontrar y no se pone la dirección completa por que hay un espacio en la dirección, ¿Cómo podría hacer que el archivo se mueva correctamente a esa dirección?
El guion bajo ni el guion normal sirven[image: ME sale esto]

Comment: Intenta colocando la carpeta que tiene espacios todo entre comillas dobles y si no escapa el espacio.

Comment: Si, si sirvió gracias